# How to check if a string contains only numbers?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim number As String = "07747(a)"

If number.... Then

endif
```

I want to be able to check inside the string to see if it only has number, if it does only contain numbers then run whatever is inside the if statment? What check do i use to check if the string only contains numeric and no alpha ot () etc ..?

What i am trying to check for is mobile numbers, so 077 234 211 should be accepted, but other alphas should not be

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like this

```
If Regex.IsMatch(number, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then

...

End If
```

Comment: That is probably the simplest answer, and it covers all bases. +1 to you.

Comment: Also, based on the updated requirements, regular epressions is probably the simplest way to go.  Too bad I can only vote you up once.

Comment: @Bala R, I'm not trying to be a jerk, just curious why you use the constructor version over the static `Regex.IsMatch(input,pattern)` method? The latter seems more legible.

Comment: Thanks @Bala R, I was just curious. Your original way worked, too, of course, it just threw me at first.

Comment: In my case, I was reading from a text file and the value I was retrieving could be either a string or a 2 digit integer (but would be retrieved as a String either way).  So, this solution worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

Use [IsNumeric Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) :

```
IsNumeric(number)
```

If you want to validate a phone number you should use a regular expression, for example:

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{3})$
```

Comment: `IsNumeric` returns true for decimal numbers, too, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: does this include spaces tho? basically number could be 0777 123456 which should be accepted

Comment: @Beginner, your post said only numbers, you should change it to numbers and spaces if that is your requirement. We are very literal here.

Comment: IsNumeric returns True on "1+". A plus-sign is obviously not a "number" (as requested by the OP). So IsNumeric is "evaluating" an "expression". A result of True only means the expression evaluated to a number. I don't think that is what is required here.

Answer (score 10):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=VS.90).aspx

You can pass nothing if you don't need the returned integer like so

```
if integer.TryParse(number,nothing) then
```

Comment: @Beginner Im not sure however you could strip the spaces using number.Replace(" ", "")

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: `Trim` will not remove spaces in-between digits.

Answer (score 8):

You may just remove all spaces and leverage LINQ [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

Use it as shown below:

```
Dim number As String = "077 234 211"
If number.Replace(" ", "").All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
    Console.WriteLine("The string is all numeric (spaces ignored)!")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("The string contains a char that is not numeric and space!")
End If
```

To **only check if a string consists of only digits** use:

```
If number.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
```