# Remove letters and special characters when entering phone number

Tags: vb.net, string

Can anyone please help me create a program that will delete special characters, like `-`, `(`, `)` or spaces, when entering phone number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
dim number as string = Regex.Replace(phoneNumber,"[^0-9]","")
```

Comment: This will only remove `(`, `)`, and `-` from the beginning of the string.  It won't remove anything from the middle of the string, nor will it remove letters or other non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Archit Garg, please reference your code you got... It's obvious and quite interesting it's exact as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139368/how-to-strip-a-string-of-all-alphas

Comment: Changed his answer to one stolen from elsewhere, and didn't give the original author credit.  Shameful.