# vb.net if text box is a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

am Sorry for the Bad Title because I Didn't know What to call the Title anyway I Want to save the text box value if it's an integer to a config file with the name IP and if it's a string to the name DNS Here is the Code :

```
Public Class ServerSettings

Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
    If IPHostInfo.Text = "" Then ' here if it's a string save it to my.settings.dns
        My.Settings.DNS() = IPHostInfo.Text

    Else : IPHostInfo.Text = ""
        My.Settings.IP() = IPHostInfo.Text 'and if it's an integer
    End If
    My.Settings.PORT() = IPInfo.Text
    My.Settings.TOut() = TOut.Text
    IPHostInfo.Text = IPHostInfo.Text
    IPInfo.Text = IPInfo.Text
    TOut.Text = TOut.Text
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel_Button.Click
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138896/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers

Comment: If used properly, the answer from the question I posted earlier should work. Use the code from the answer to check if the input contains only numbers. If not, handle it as text. Though, what input do you call numbers? If it's an actual IP with dots you need to change the regex from the answer to handle those.

Comment: @Ossie7 how that what am trying to know.

Comment: @Ossie7 in the user setting should i change the ip type to integer or string?

Comment: Since an IP is a combination of numbers and dots it is best to save the IP as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine if a string is a valid IP address, I think the simplest way to do so is to simply call `IPAddress.TryParse`, for instance:

```
If IPAddress.TryParse(IPHostInfo.Text, Nothing) Then
    ' It's an IP Address
    My.Settings.IP() = IPHostInfo.Text
Else
    ' It's not an IP Address, so it must be a DNS name
    My.Settings.DNS() = IPHostInfo.Text
End If
```