# How to split $dollar amount with Comma sepatated string

Tags: vb.net

I have below string and I try below output using comma split function in vb.net.
but no luck.

input:

```
"Änanth,$10,250,$10,000,$1200"
```

Output:

1. Ananth
2. $10,250
3. $10,000
4. $1200

How to build the above output?

Comment: What's wrong with `String.Split`?

Comment: If you string always has `,$` in the place where you want to split, then you need to split with that. If not, then there's really no way to know where the strings need to be split.

Answer (score 3):

I think your input is a string, so you can use the String.Split method as descriped [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).

This may work for you:

```
Module Example
Public Sub Main()
  Dim value As String = "This is a short string."
  Dim delimiter As Char = "s"c
  Dim substrings() As String = value.Split(delimiter)
  For Each substring In substrings
     Console.WriteLine(substring)
  Next
End Sub
End Module

' The example displays the following output:
'     Thi
'      i
'      a
'     hort
'     tring.
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks For Your Swift Reply..But It wont work ...I Cant able to use comma or dollar as delimeter.. If I use "," its returning the output is like Ananth
$10
250
$10
000
$1200 ..but i want above output that whole amount with dollar

Comment: You could try to split your string with string.Split(",$"), and then add the dollar again when you print the values

Comment: Ok ..but chararcter also coming in the same string so i cant able to add dollar again..is there any regex ?

Comment: You can add the dollar again when you are iterating through the substrings array: 
Dim substrings() As String = value.Split(delimiter)
  For Each substring In substrings
     Console.WriteLine("$"+substring)
  Next

Comment: Ok If I added dollar again means output seems "$Ananth $10,250" etc ..but i want only for append dollar with amount not the character string...

Comment: If you check if the string is a number like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138896/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers), it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can't use just a comma as the delimiter, but if you use the  standalone `Split` function, rather than the `Split` function built into string objects, you can use multiple characters as a delimiter. Like below. I'm assuming you're writing a console app, so this should work

```
Sub Main()
    Dim strElements() As String = Split(testString,",$")
    Console.WriteLine("1. " & strElements(0))
    For i As Integer = 1 To strElements.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString & ". $" & strElements(i))
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

its Ok...but My string is below format and i want the above output

1,1,