# Textbox converts date into number

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Mid(TextBox1.Value, 4, 2) > 12 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date, please re-enter", vbCritical
        TextBox1.Value = vbNullString
        TextBox1.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
    TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    StartDate = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

This code works well for me and my colleagues to make sure the value entered in the textbox is a date. However, a colleague from a different country (but also with the `dd.mm.yyyy` date-format) gets weird results.

For example: If he enters `01.10.2017` the TextBox automatically format the date into `20.03.4917`.

I suspect that in this case the entered value is not recognized as a date but as a number because `01102017` will transform into `20.03.4917` in Excel if you convert it as a date.

Does anyone have a suggestion or a guess how to work around this problem?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the date by `.` into an array `ArrInput` and then use `DateSerial` to make it a real date, that you can format.

```
Dim ArrInput As Variant
ArrInput = Split(TextBox1.Value, ".")

'StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date)) 'I see no use in this at all
TextBox1.Value = Format$(DateSerial(ArrInput(2), ArrInput(1), ArrInput(0)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
StartDate = TextBox1.Value
```

---

The issue with `Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")` is that here you let Excel guess which date format the string in `TextBox1.Value` is. It automatically casts into a number which is then converted into a string again.

---

To avoid date misunderstandings I recommend always to use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This is the only date format that is human readable and cannot be misunderstood. It also has benefits when sorting by dates that are actually strings.

---

To make your validation even more solid use something like:

```
Dim ArrInput As Variant
ArrInput = Split(TextBox1.Value, ".")

Dim ValidDate As Boolean

If UBound(ArrInput) = 2 Then 'make sure there are exactly two dots in the date
    If ArrInput(1) > 0 And ArrInput(1) <= 12 And _ 'month <= 12
    ArrInput(0) > 0 And ArrInput(0) <= 31 Then     'day <= 31
        ValidDate = True
    End If
Else
    ValidDate = False
End If

If Not ValidDate Then
    MsgBox "Invalid date, please re-enter in format dd.mm.yyyy", vbCritical
    TextBox1.Value = vbNullString
    TextBox1.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

TextBox1.Value = Format$(DateSerial(ArrInput(2), ArrInput(1), ArrInput(0)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
StartDate = TextBox1.Value
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you mate. It works well for me. I'll let you know later if it works for him as well.:)

Comment: @Sven to prevent stupid user input you can make your date validation more solid. I also suggest to inform the user in the msgbox how the format of the date is required. See my edit.

Comment: Why not have 3 input boxes with a relevant range of numbers specified for each box? one each for year, month, date etc? Avoids any dot missing or commas etc as you can "put" them or concatenate them together.

Comment: @SolarMike For example because you have a lot of coding to do to accept pasting a date then ;( And fiddling the pasted date into the boxes would be the same work as validating one box.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ok, sorry just an idea - worked when I was using the original excel macro language, we used 3 dropdown lists...

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, of course that works perfectly but you have to give up the ability of pasting a date, which can be a knock out. At least for me it always was a knock out.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It works! Thank you sir! And also thank you for the suggestions to make everything user-friendly. I will definitely integrate it in my tool

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Seems like his date settings are dd/mm/yyyy. I transformed the code with "/" instead of the "." so it works now for him. Is there a solution where I can define more then one ArrInput for dates?

Comment: @Sven the issue is that you never know if someone puts in `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` if you allow that. So force the user to put in the date in your desired format `dd.mm.yyyy` or even better as I suggested `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you let him put the date with slashes you might end up with a wrong date.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that your colleague enters the text string "01102017" without dots.
You might want to convert such kind of entries into a valid date:

```
'  "01102017" => 01.10.2017      - 8 chars variant
'  "011017"   => 01.10.2017      - 6 chars variant
```

This needs to be done of cause prior to a date conversion.



Add a log of the input value to a free cell range and 
have the workbook sent back to you:

```
...
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Range("Z1").value = "'" & TextBox1.Value
    If Mid(TextBox1.Value, 4, 2) > 12 Then
...
```

Check if only numbers are used:
[How to check if a string contains only numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138896/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-only-numbers)


and check the length of the string (6 or 8 chars variant) and check if the year part is within a valid range => try to convert to a date and offer it to the user.

Comment: This was also my first guess, but he promised me on the phone that he entered the values with a dots

Comment: You might create a kind of log into the workbook itself and have the workbook sent to you after he entered the value: